# Fit panel on paper

Tags: java, swing, printing, charts

So I have 2 panel in 1 panel. On 1 panel is chart, and on second is some information. I want to print that panel witch contains that two panel. So I used some tricks for panel to fit to paper, but it didn't work fully. Here is my printing job:

```
public void printComponenet(Component comp){

      PrinterJob pj = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
      pj.setJobName(" Print Component ");
      PageFormat pf = pj.defaultPage();
      pf.setOrientation(PageFormat.LANDSCAPE);

      pj.setPrintable (new Printable() {    
            public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int pageNum){

                if(pageNum > 0) 
                {
                    return Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE;
                }

                Dimension compSize = comp.getPreferredSize();
                comp.setSize(compSize);

                Dimension printSize = new Dimension();
                printSize.setSize(pf.getImageableWidth(), pf.getImageableHeight());

                double scaleFactor = getScaleFactorToFit(compSize, printSize);

                if(scaleFactor > 1d) 
                {
                    scaleFactor = 1d;
                }

                double scaleWidth = compSize.width * scaleFactor;
                double scaleHeight = compSize.height * scaleFactor;

                Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();

                double x = ((pf.getImageableWidth() - scaleWidth) / 2d) + pf.getImageableX();
                double y = ((pf.getImageableHeight() - scaleHeight) / 2d) + pf.getImageableY();

                AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
                at.translate(x, y);
                at.scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
                g2.transform(at);
                comp.printAll(g2);
                g2.dispose();

                comp.revalidate();
                return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
            }
      }, pf);
      if (pj.printDialog() == false)
      return;

      try {
            pj.print();
      } catch (PrinterException ex) {
            // handle exception
      }
}
```

And when I print that panel, it looks like this.[image: Here]

How should I fix it? Bottom side of paper is okay, I just didn't screenshoted it fully.

Comment: if the bottom side is OK, then what problems specifically are you having?

Comment: If you look closely, you will see that on top side of paper, numbers are cut, and a bit of chart is cut

Comment: Where is your `getScaleFactorToFit(...)` method? And did you up-vote MadProgrammer's answer (where it looks like you borrowed this code)?

Comment: Well it is same like MadProgrammer answer (yes i voted up). It's same method. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17904518/fit-scale-jcomponent-to-page-being-printed

Answer (score 1):

Instead of scaling the rendered graphics, which will only worsen [resampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_scaling) artifact, override the `getPreferredSize()` method of the enclosing `Component` and specify the desired size. Use a layout such as `FlowLayout` to preclude resizing. As it appears that you are using `JFreeChart`, related examples may be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10277372/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17507061/230513).