# How to highlight or focus particular pie section in a pie chart using JFreeChart

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart

I am developing a simple pie chart using JFreeChart in Swing application. Based on key event, I want to focus or highlight particular pie section of a pie chart. 
Any idea what api in JFreeChart provides such feature?

Comment: Cross-posted [here](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=117766).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`setExplodePercent()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/PiePlot.html#setExplodePercent-java.lang.Comparable-double-) on your `PiePlot`, like they show [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17507061/261156).

```
JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createPieChart(…);
PiePlot plot = (PiePlot) chart.getPlot();
plot.setExplodePercent(KEY, PERCENT);
```

> I need some method to set a border or set a focus to the section based on some event, e.g. mouse hover on particular section.

I tried @trashgod's idea by adding a [`ChartMouseListener`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartMouseListener.html) to `createDemoPanel()` in [`PieChartDemo1`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/demo/PieChartDemo1.html). Hover over each section to see the effect. Try different values for the `percent` to get the effect you want.

[image: pie chart]

```
panel.addChartMouseListener(new ChartMouseListener() {

    private Comparable lastKey;

    @Override
    public void chartMouseMoved(ChartMouseEvent e) {
        ChartEntity entity = e.getEntity();
        if (entity instanceof PieSectionEntity) {
            PieSectionEntity section = (PieSectionEntity) entity;
            PiePlot plot = (PiePlot) chart.getPlot();
            if (lastKey != null) {
                plot.setExplodePercent(lastKey, 0);
            }
            Comparable key = section.getSectionKey();
            plot.setExplodePercent(key, 0.10);
            lastKey = key;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void chartMouseClicked(ChartMouseEvent e) {
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.
But I need some method to set a border or set a focus to the section based on some event (Eg: Mouse hover on particular section) rather than exploding that section. Is there any way?
Thanks!

Comment: @ChayaShetty: Add a `ChartMouseListener` to your `ChartPanel` and invoke `setExplodePercent()` in `chartMouseMoved()`.

Comment: @ChayaShetty: I added an example to try. A smaller percent like `0.05` may be good.