# Update JavaFx chart from Swing

Tags: java, javafx

I have a JavaFx Application which plot a chart.

```
public class Test2 extends Application {      
  @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
    final SwingNode chartSwingNode = new SwingNode();
    chartSwingNode.setContent(
      new ChartPanel(generatePieChart())      
    );

    stage.setScene(
      new Scene(new StackPane(chartSwingNode))
    );
    stage.show();
  }

  private JFreeChart generatePieChart() {
    DefaultPieDataset dataSet = new DefaultPieDataset();
    dataSet.setValue("China",        1344.0);
    dataSet.setValue("India",        1241.0);
    dataSet.setValue("United States", 310.5);

    return ChartFactory.createPieChart(
      "Population 2011", dataSet, true, true, false
    );
  } 

  public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
}
```

Then I call it from Swing using a button.

```
_btnStart.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {
      new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Application.launch(Test2.class);

        }
      }.start();   
  }
});
```

When I click button, the chart will be shown. Now I want to update the chart. How can I pass value to Test2 class and update the chart? Should I use JFXPanel instead?

Comment: Do you need Swing? JFreeChart works in JavaFX, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44688314/230513) and [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44967809/230513).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need to make it in such a way, why not using a [Singleton](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073352/core-java/simply-singleton.html)?

Create a class ChartSingleton.java:

```
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.data.general.DefaultPieDataset;

public class ChartSingleton {
  private static ChartSingleton instance = null;
  private static ChartPanel chartPanel = null;

  private ChartSingleton() {
    chartPanel = new ChartPanel(generatePieChart());
  }

  public static ChartSingleton getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
      instance = new ChartSingleton();
    }
    return instance;
  }

  private JFreeChart generatePieChart() {
    DefaultPieDataset dataSet = new DefaultPieDataset();
    dataSet.setValue("China",        1344.0);
    dataSet.setValue("India",        1241.0);
    dataSet.setValue("United States", 310.5);

    return ChartFactory.createPieChart(
            "Population 2011", dataSet, true, true, false
    );
  }

  public ChartPanel getChartPanel() {
    return chartPanel;
  }
}
```

Then replace the line:

```
chartSwingNode.setContent(new ChartPanel(generatePieChart()));
```

With this:

```
ChartSingleton chartSingleton = ChartSingleton.getInstance();
chartSwingNode.setContent(chartSingleton.getChartPanel());
```

Now you can update/modify your chart through the ChartSingleton class using:

```
chartSingleton.youNewMethodToModifyOrUpdateTheChart();
```