# javafx adding second scale

Tags: javafx, charts, scale

I use LineChart from JavaFX and I want to add second scale on my chart on right side. 
I have tested JFreeChart, but It's used objects from awt (Circle, Color etc.). I use such class from JavaFX, so JFreeChart not resolve my problem.
Do somebody have any ideas how it can be realyzed? Thanks for help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D48LY.png)

Comment: [tag:jfreechart] supports this, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13362809/230513).

Comment: @trashgod I use Javafx. JFreeChart based on AWT if I dont mistakes. How I can use this together?

Comment: https://github.com/JKostikiadis/MultiAxisScatterChart

Comment: @ВладЧеловянов: No, it works in JavaFX, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44688314/230513).

Comment: @trashgod Oh, I test it with JavaFX. I need delete all objects with Color or Shape because It use JavaFX objects... Its very bad idea... What I can user awt elevents with JavaFX together?

Comment: @SedrickJefferson Its ScatterChart. Unfortunately, I use LineChart

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the new requirements and a [mcve] that exhibits any problem you encounter with your chosen approach.