# Percentage Accuracy issue in JFreeChart Pie-chart

Tags: java, jfreechart

I'm using Pie-chart of [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) library for my need.  
And i want to display percentage with total values in pie-chart. So, i searched over google. And i found [**this solution**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17507061/5813861) which is answered by @trashgod.

Now as per answer given by him i created class which is as following :

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.labels.PieSectionLabelGenerator;
import org.jfree.chart.labels.StandardPieSectionLabelGenerator;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PiePlot;
import org.jfree.data.general.DefaultPieDataset;

public class TestPieChart {
    private static final String KEY1 = "Datum 1";
    public static final String KEY2 = "Datum 2";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DefaultPieDataset dataset = new DefaultPieDataset();
        dataset.setValue(KEY1, 45045); //49
        dataset.setValue(KEY2, 53955); //151

        JFreeChart someChart = ChartFactory.createPieChart(
            "Header", dataset, true, true, false);
        PiePlot plot = (PiePlot) someChart.getPlot();
        plot.setSectionPaint(KEY1, Color.green);
        plot.setSectionPaint(KEY2, Color.red);
        plot.setExplodePercent(KEY1, 0.10);
        plot.setSimpleLabels(true);

        PieSectionLabelGenerator gen = new StandardPieSectionLabelGenerator(
            "{0}: {1} ({2})", new DecimalFormat("0"), new DecimalFormat("0%"));
        plot.setLabelGenerator(gen);

        JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(new ChartPanel(someChart) {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(400, 300);
            }
        });
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

What it gives output as follows:

[image]

In which percentage was **55%** and **46%**, Total is **101%**  
 (Because it is taking upper limit for both values like 54.5 then 55)

But at the same time if i take value for **KEY1** as 49 and **KEY2** as 151, then it is giving accurate result as follows:  
 (Sum of both in this case is 100%) 
[image]

**So, My question is : Why JFreeChart is performing different for different values? 
 and is there any solution to fix this (total percentage will not cross 100) ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The percentage calculation performed by the label generator's abstract parent, seen [here](https://github.com/jfree/jfreechart/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jfree/chart/labels/AbstractPieItemLabelGenerator.java#L121), and the formatter's default rounding, discussed [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html), are both correct. If desired, you can change the precision of the *displayed* percentage by specifying a different `percentFormat` when constructing the [`StandardPieSectionLabelGenerator`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/labels/StandardPieSectionLabelGenerator.html):

```
PieSectionLabelGenerator gen = new StandardPieSectionLabelGenerator(
    "{0}: {1} ({2})", new DecimalFormat("0"), new DecimalFormat("0.0%"));
```

[image]

Note that `45.5% + 54.5% = 100%`.